# Remote Desktop username and password

Tags: remote-desktop

Trying to remote desktop into my work laptop. It's a work account.

I can get the login screen, but there is no username/password combination that it'll accept. What hoops are required for Remote Desktop to work on Windows 10? I cannot find any useable information anywhere about this.

I've tried logging in with the result from `whoami`, but that doesn't work. So, yeah, what are the necessary steps to make this thing work?

Comment: There are no steps - just log in.  Did you get to the correct computer?  Possibly not.

Comment: Many people screw this up (not saying that YOU are).. what kind of account are you trying to connect with?  is it local or domain to the machine you are trying to RDS to?

Comment: @John I've used both the IP and computer name as the target. Why would you assume I just wasn't getting the right computer?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It's a domain account. Trying to log in as `AzureAD\MyName`, same as the result from `whoami` on the target computer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether it's a domain account or a local account you're logging on with, you may need to qualify your username for the Remote Desktop logon.

For example, if you normally log on as

```
Contoso\Jade.Jones
```

then that should continue to work in the Remote Desktop dialog.

However, if you normally log on to local machine account Jade.Jones, you will need to use

```
.\Jade.Jones
```

to tell Remote Desktop it is a local account on the target machine. Otherwise it may try to prefix your name with a default domain name which is incorrect for the current context.

Answer (score 0):

On your local PC, enable group policy "**Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administratives Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections-Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services**"

On remote PC (your work laptop), add the user account (which will be used to login to the remote PC) to **Remote Desktop Users** group under Local Users and Groups.

Then use mstsc.exe to remote connect your work laptop, putting the IP address and the user account.

[image]